# Why is awk seemingly failing to completely store a very large array?

Tags: arrays, memory, awk

I'm using the following code to identify the 99th percentile of a list of numbers:

```
sort -n file.txt  | awk '{all[NR] = $0} END{print all[int(NR*0.99 - 0.01)]}'
```

where file.txt looks like:

```
50
150
75
313
```

etc.

This works fine for small (20,000) line files but for bigger ones (140-790 million lines) it is giving a smaller number than when you just sort the text file into a new file, and go down to the appropriate line. As far as I can tell awk isn't giving an error that it's run out of memory, but just prints out a number at around the 40th percentile for a 140M line file. I can implement this step a different way, but I was just wondering if anyone knew why this might be happening? From looking at other posts it doesn't seem like awk has a maximum array size so not sure what's happening.

Comment: How much memory do you have? Which awk are you using? Using 100M values with `seq 1 100000000 | awk ...` What is the result? On my laptop with 16 GB previous uses about 82 % mem (based on `top`).

Comment: Not an explanation of your problem but it would probably be better to pass the number of lines to your `awk` script and print only the relevant line: `awk -vn=$(wc -l < file.txt) 'NR == int(n*0.99 - 0.01)'`.

Comment: James: I was using gnu awk 4.0.4. The cluster has around 120Gb memory. The command you first suggested is giving the correct result, suggesting it's not a problem with awk. My actual file used a lot more memory though, so it's probably just a problem of giving it sufficient memory, thanks! Renaud: thanks, yes I have implemented it in a similar way, I was using someone elses code but was just curious why this step didn't seem to be working.

Comment: How about: `END{ line = int(NR*0.99 - 0.01); print "line ", line, " = ", all[line] }` to check that the script is printing the line you think it is printing.